# Separate APP ENGINE module from Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, google-app-engine, migrate

I have a running project which depends on a Android APP and Google Cloud.
It was started with a previous versions of Android Studio 2.X so I started a project and added the app engine module.
Nowadays I'm still using this project but Android Studio 3.0 no longer can handle new App Engine modules, so I would like to separate this App Engine module into a independent IntelliJ project.

Which would be the best way to achieve that?